# Removing runtime listeners in corona sdk between the screens

Tags: coronasdk

In my application I have used many RuntimeListeners,the listeners in one screen will not get removed in other screens.The other screens will get loaded on a button click.The screens are working fine but the event listener of previous screen still remains causing problem to it.
I have tried with removeEventListener at the tap of the button,the listener gets removed for the first time but for the second time when I change the screens the event listeners remain.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Try using the storyboard API. It is in the newest 704 build for Corona.

For the events, remember to remove them in exitScene().

```
function scene:enterScene(event)
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",AnimalSelfHelp)
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",SurpriseHandling)
end

function scene:exitScene(event)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",AnimalSelfHelp)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",SurpriseHandling)
end
```